# Reactor: Mono: combining two methods doOnError and onErrroMap

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactor

I am new to Reactive programming, so can use some help. I have below code where I am not liking two different methods for error handling.
 I want to combine them in one method. What is the correct approach?

```
mono.doOnError(error -> logError(error))
    .onErrorMap(
        t -> !(t instanceof DatabaseException),
           t -> DatabaseExceptionMapper.mapException(t));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the log in the `onErrorMap` itself.

```
flux.onErrorMap(err -> {
    logError(err);
    //return transformed exception
})
```